# C++:Boost: Does Managed Shared Memory Require a Semaphore lock?

Tags: c++, boost, shared-memory

I have two processes sharing a vector of strings.

- Process A will only push strings into the vector
- Process B will read the string and remove it from the vector

Does this require a semaphore in order to prevent data corruption? Does boost already handle this using `managed_shared_memory` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boost managed shared memory DOES require a semaphore lock, otherwise the processes can read and write bad data- and unexpected behaviour will occur. (segmentation faults or otherwise).

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell boost handles it. [This page should have all the information you need](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/interprocess/managed_memory_segments.html#interprocess.managed_memory_segments.managed_memory_segment_features.index_types)

"Boost.Interprocess offers managed shared memory between processes using managed_shared_memory or managed_mapped_file. Two processes just map the same the memory mappable resource and read from and write to that object."